# How to Remove This Item in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIe1e.jpg

This thing (inside blue circle area) appeared in filter panel area while I changed the visualization into packed bubbles. I've already hide the filter panel, but this little panel is still there. I'm a newbie so I still don't know much about Tableau.

How can I remove this?